# how to configure jenkins scheduler to run a job every hour at a specific time/min?

Tags: jenkins

I'm new to Jenkins.

I need to configure two jobs to run every hour 3 times, at a specific minute.

For example:

```
job1 to run at: 08:00, 08:20, 08:40, 09:00, 09:20, 09:40, etc
job2 to run at: 08:10, 08:30, 08:50, 09:10, 09:30, 09:50, etc
```

Is this correct?

```
job1: (00, 20, 40) * * * *
job2: (10, 30, 50) * * * *
```

Or should it be like that?

```
job1: 00,20,40 * * * *
job2: 10,30,50 * * * *
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example will do the Job.

```
job1: 00,20,40 * * * *
job2: 10,30,50 * * * *
```

Also (besides the docs in Jenkins itself) another resource to test around CRON: https://crontab.guru/